# VBA formula for correlation coefficient between two variables where one of the variables is the sumproduct of two other variables

Tags: arrays, vba, sumproduct

I need to calculate the correlation coefficient between two variables where one of them is the sumproduct of two other variables. In the following example I need to calculate CORREL which is the correlation coefficient between SUMPR and X. SUMPR is the sumproduct of values A and B with each of the values Y1 and Y2.

[image]

Is there a way I can find CORREL without having to calculate SUMPR first? In other words, can I pass SUMPR in the correlation coefficient formula as a variable? I need to do that for very large dynamic tables and calculating SUMPR first takes a lot of space and time.
Thank you

Comment: What is your `SUMPRODUCT()` formula. Put here in the post.

Comment: =SUMPRODUCT($B$4:$C$4,E4:F4)     =SUMPRODUCT($B$4:$C$4,E5:F5)     =SUMPRODUCT($B$4:$C$4,E6:F6)  where B4:C4 are the values A and B, and E4:F4 to E6:E6 are each one of the values Y1 and Y2. I have a code to do it stepwise with named ranges but I want to use each of the sumproducts as a variable in the correlation coefficient formula

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this array formula as oer screenshot-

```
=CORREL($A$2*D2:D4+$B$2*E2:E4,H2:H4)
```

Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> to evaluate the formula as it is an array formula.

[image]

If you have `Office365` then it will work as normal without array entry.

Comment: Glad to know! If you found the answer useful please mark it as answered. Tick mark it.